# How to pass a returned value of a function to another function while both functions require different messages from a user in Python 3?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

Recently I have got stuck with a problem. The thing is that I am trying to create a bot in Telegram using *telebot*. The core of the problem is mixing inputs from users. I looked through various articles and decided to get rid of major global variables that get mixed while multiple users activate the bot. As I was trying to use only locals and passing values from a function to another, I couldn't solve the case: when function **def dicties(url_new)** managed to return value - then I got no idea how to use the returned value in function **def answer(message)** - I need the dictionaries for counting the adjusted exchange rate.

I have tried putting all functions under def answer(message), but it requires a specific keyboard answer (like "Доллар Сингапура") from def day_step(message) instead of a message from a user - the messages are different, otherwise the code crashes. So, is there a way of not using global variables and saving the return somewhere without inputting message again?

```
def urlnew(message):
date = str(message.text)
url_new = url.replace('dd/mm/year', date)
print(url_new)
return url_new


def dicties(url_new):
    currency_dictionary = get_currencies_dictionary(get_data(url_new))
    nominal_dictionary = get_nominals_dictionary(get_data(url_new))
    print(currency_dictionary)
    print(nominal_dictionary)
    return currency_dictionary, nominal_dictionary


def day_step(message):
    dicties(urlnew(message))
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=None)
    itembtn_sgd = types.KeyboardButton('Доллар Сингапура')
    itembtn_back_to_dates = types.KeyboardButton('Вернуться к вводу даты')
    markup.add(itembtn_back_to_dates, itembtn_sgd)
    msg1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Выбери одну или вернись к выбору даты', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg1, answer)
 

def answer(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
    if message.text == 'Вернуться к вводу даты':
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, welcoming)
    elif message.text == 'Доллар Сингапура':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Вот столько стоил один доллар Сингапура в рублях: ' + str(float(currency_dictionary['SGD'] / nominal_dictionary['SGD'])), reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Упс, что-то не так', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Но ты можешь посмотреть сам по ссылке: ' + str(url_new))
```

Thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i've understood correctly, but I think I would do in this way;

```
def answer(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
    url_new = urlnew(message)
    currency_dictionary, nominal_dictionary = dicties(url_new)
    if message.text == 'Вернуться к вводу даты':
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, welcoming)
    elif message.text == 'Доллар Сингапура':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Вот столько стоил один доллар Сингапура в рублях: ' + str(float(currency_dictionary['SGD'] / nominal_dictionary['SGD'])), reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Упс, что-то не так', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Но ты можешь посмотреть сам по ссылке: ' + str(url_new))
```

Comment: Not exactly. The thing I need is like that: the url function expects strict format date - 05/12/2020, for example. And the function asnwer expects phrases only from if-elif options. And in case I adopt your example of code, the url function message gets mixed with def answer and crashes, because it cannot process the  url-message.